# I would like to rewrite it into C #, but do not know how to amend the red mark（xamarin Android）

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How can I convert a `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` into `List<Dictionary<String, String>>`?

But `Java.lang.Object`

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map<K,V>` is `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`
`java.lang.Object` is `System.Object` which is often aliased as just `object`

But you really have to specify your question more specificly.